# Quotient of a CW pair is a CW-complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-writing, quotient-spaces, cw-complexes

I am trying to prove (in a strict way) that **$X/A$ inherits a natural CW-complex structure from a CW-pair $(X,A)$**.

I start with the following inductive definition of a CW-complex:

> *Let $\{\mathcal A_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ be a sequence of disjoint sets such that $\mathcal A_0\ne\emptyset$. Starting with this sequence we inductively construct a sequence of topological spaces $\{X^n\}$ as follow*:
>
> - For $n=0$ we put $X^0=\mathcal A_0$ with the discrete topology on $\mathcal A_0$.
> - If $X^{n-1}$ has already been constructed, then put $X^n=X^{n-1}$ if $\mathcal A_n=\emptyset$. However if $\mathcal A_n\ne\emptyset$, we assume that we have a family of maps $\{\varphi_\alpha^n:\partial D_\alpha^n\to X^{n-1}:\alpha\in\mathcal A_n\}$ and define:
>   $$X^n=\Big(X^{n-1}\bigsqcup_{\alpha\in\mathcal A_n}D_\alpha^n\Big)/\sim_n$$
>   where $\sim_n$ is the equivalence relation generated by $x\sim \varphi_\alpha^n(x)$ if $x\in \partial D_\alpha^n$.

> Then a CW-complex $X$ is the **colimit** of the sequence of topological embeddings $X^0\hookrightarrow X^1\hookrightarrow\ldots$ as defined above

In order to prove that $X/A$ is a CW complex I want to show the following:

> The quotient space $\tilde X^n=X^n/A$ determines a sequence of topological ${X^n}$ as the definition above.

I think that the best way to do this is proceed inductively

1. First show that $\tilde X^0=X^0/A$ is a discrete space (trivial) and that $\tilde X^1=X^1/A$ is homeomorphic to $\big(\tilde X^0\bigsqcup_{\alpha\in\mathcal A_0}D_\alpha^n\big)/\sim_0$
2. Suppose $\tilde X^n=X^n/A$ is homeomorphic to $\big(\tilde X^{n-1}\bigsqcup_{\alpha\in\mathcal A_n}D_\alpha^n\big)/\sim_n$ and conclude $\tilde X^{n+1}$ is homeomorphic to $\big(\tilde X^n\bigsqcup_{\alpha\in A_{n+1}}D_\alpha^{n+1}\big)/\sim_{n+1}$

Any help? How can I construct these homeomorphisms?

Comment: Hint: you must make use of the fact that $(X, A)$ is a CW pair: i.e., $A$ is a subcomplex of $X$. In $X/A$, $A$ collapses to a single $0$-cell, $a$ say, and you can forget the other cells in $A$. The cells in $X$ but not in $A$ together with $a$ give the cells of $X/A$. The attaching maps for an $n$-cell in $X/A$ for $n \ge 1$ is just what you get by composing the attaching map for the corresponding cell in $X$ with the projection of $X^{n-1}$ onto $X^{n-1}/A^{n-1}$.